# asp.net membership provider Guid userID

Tags: asp.net

I need (I think) to get the current logged in userID so that I can update one of my tables that uses this userID as a foreign key. The problem is that the userID in the database does not match with this:

```
Guid currentUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
currentUser.toString();
```

results in dffaca0c-ae0b-8549-8073-1639985740be

whereas when I look in the database, it is 0CCAFADF0BAE498580731639985740BE

Why are they different values? (I only have one user). I am using an oracle database and provider for asp.net, but shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: try supplying `Page.User.Identity.Name` to the `GetUser()` method instead of using the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe these are the same values, but the display order is different.  Looking at the 2 values:

```
dffaca0c-ae0b-8549-8073-1639985740be
0CCAFADF-0BAE-4985-8073-1639985740BE
```

The ordering of bytes for the first 3 segments is of a different order:

```
0CCA FADF => FADF 0CCA => DFFA CA0C == dffaca0c

0BAE => AE 0B == ae0b

4985 => 85 49 == 8549
```

As @x0n comments, this looks like a difference in endianness with Oracle.  According the [this description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Basic_structure) of the structure, the endianness of the first 8 bytes is system dependent, while the endianness of the last 8 bytes is specifically big endian.

Comment: endian differences on oracle?

Comment: yup :) now I have to figure out why this is the case. hmm, might be how oracle stores the values in the database...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and came up with this which resolved the issue:

```
 public static string TranslateOraceEndianUserID()
    {
        MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid g = new Guid(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
        byte[] b = g.ToByteArray();
        string UserID = BitConverter.ToString(b, 0).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        return UserID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe also try using HttpContext.Curent.User to get the current user?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the Lower Case User Name column to create the foreign Key. It is always unique. Maybe not the best option but it is the simplest and works well. I have used it in several projects.