# ProviderUserKey returning wrong key

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, asp.net-membership

I am trying the following code

aspx:

```
Username: <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserName"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Password: <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" onclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text.Trim()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text.Trim()))
    {
        string username = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
        string password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
            string userid = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        }
 }
```

The value that I get in userid is different from what I have in database. What am I doing wrong. I have tried `MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser()` but it returns null

Note:
I am using Oracle with asp.net membership configured.

**Edit:**
Userid in database: 161863BC7C244AADBF27F5F6250AF99C

Userid in userid var: bc631816-247c-ad4a-bf27-f5f6250af99c

Comment: I think its something to do with the Oracle way of storing data. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5447244/799558)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, seems like `Oracle` is storing the user guid in different order. if you really want to get the same guid in the database, you need a workaround. Check [this  code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/247677/Oracle-ASP-Net-membership-provider-ProviderUserKey). The author used a method to translate the guid :

```
public static string TranslateOraceEndianUserID() 
    { 
        MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser(); 
        Guid g = new Guid(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString()); 
        byte[] b = g.ToByteArray(); 
        string UserID = BitConverter.ToString(b, 0).Replace("-", string.Empty); 
        return UserID; 
    }
```

This is untested though. the author says

> following method was created which resolves the issue for me

Comment: and this solved my issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/7245900/1099235

Comment: @ZedBee The answerer is the same author of the article :). I didn't notice the answer in the link I gave you earlier

Comment: :) now trapped in another problem. Since I am saving the userid to one of my tables.. directly saving the userid gives problem. Wondering whether I should convert it back to the oracle format.

Comment: @ZedBee Maybe you shouldn't translate it in the first place ?

Comment: lolz.. yep I realized that was a wrong question.. :)

Comment: @ZedBee lol. Its ok, someone else might find this helpful. If you really want both then create two properties one for each.